# Windows shortcuts inserting last stroked key

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use any of the shortcuts in my system, it first insert my last stroked key belongs to that shortcut. I also tried 4 diffirent keyboard models in my laptop, but its still same.

For example if I copy "`Hello World!`" text with <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> and then paste it with <kbd>CTRL + V</kbd>, it writes `V` key before the copied text, pasted text becoming "`vHello World!`".

Another example is, if I select "`Hello World!`" text with <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd> key and then stroke <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (or any key) in my keyboard, it writes the `A` key.

This is so annoying... Here is my hardware and software specifications,

- **System Model:** HP ZBook Studio G5
- **Operating System:** Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18363)
- **BIOS:** Q71 Ver. 01.11.03

Edit:

- My problem is not happening in safe-mode.
- I've also tried to disable all of my start-up applications.
- Toggle keys and Sticky keys are disabled.

Comment: Do you have any accessibility options enabled, such as sticky keys or toggle keys? Toggle keys would do this in certain situations.

Comment: @shawn Toggle keys and Sticky keys are disabled in my system.

Comment: Try the on-screen keyboard to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @Candy Yes same problem is happening.

Comment: Is this happening when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Nope, it is not happening.

Comment: Do you have any HP utilities installed that may change the behavior of function keys? If not, look for one. If it's already installed then check the settings or uninstall it.

Comment: Something is intercepting your keypresses and doing a poor job of handling them. I would suspect, in this order: 1. Some HP application / utility / driver / bloatware, 2. Some badly behaved device driver (I had a bluetooth dongle once which for some reason contained a caps lock OSD which would pull me out of fullscreen any time I hit caps lock), 3. A virus or keylogger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the problem doesn't arrive in Safe Mode, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for this weird behavior.
Here is how to find that application.

The tool to use is the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Autoruns shows all the programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return them later with another click.
You may avoid listing Microsoft products by using the menu
*Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*, *Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*.

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches and reboot,
drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).
Start with products that may pertain to the clipboard.

Comment: Task manager also has this functionality in Windows 8+